# Moving an object from a height to the ground at constant velocity, difference between normal vs applied force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, statics

An object is at rest on top of a level surface such as a table at height $h$. Under this condition, a normal force is acting on the object from the surface of the table as well as the force of gravity. I wish to bring the object to the ground at a height of $0$ with constant velocity. Do I have to exert a force to the object, or is the force required to maintain constant velocity throughout the descent the normal force from my hands?

Comment: Your hands *are* the surface. Correct?

Comment: The situation is a bit vague energy will be required only to impart a velocity to object since it's at rest in rest of the path work done by normal force and mg cancel each other and this energy means some force was acting on it

Answer (score 0):

If you are lowering the object straight down, then the normal force from your hands is the force which you are exerting on the object.